# Drag and drop module - Display uploaded images inline

Tags: views, media

Using [drag and drop](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload) module I am able to upload multiple images but once it is uploaded, it is displaying in table format creating new row for each image uploaded.

How do I display images inline and remove link below each image.

This is the current rendered structure

```
<table id="edit-field-images-und--3-table" class="sticky-enabled tabledrag-processed">

 <thead><tr><th>File information</th><th class="tabledrag-hide">Weight</th><th>Operations</th> </tr></thead>
..
..
..
</table>
```

Thanks!